# What can be said about time complexity of $C(N) + A(N).B(N)$?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

Let A(N)= Θ(N)

B(N) = Θ(N) and

C(N) = Ω(N)

Then, What can be said about  C(N) + A(N) * B(N) ?

Answer (score 2):

You can show that D(n) = C(n) + A(n) * B(n) is Ω(n^2) - this follows (almost) immediately from the definitions of the complexity classes. You cannot show anything in the way of an upper-bound, complexity-wise, since C(N) can be as complex is you like.

To be more explicit: Let n_A and n_B be such that for n > n_A we have A(n) > k_A * n and for n > n_B we have B(n) > k_B * n. These exist since A and B are, specifically, Ω(n). Remembering C(n) is non-negative, we have, for n > max(n_A, n_B): C(n) + A(n) * B(n) > A(n) * B(n) > k_A * n * k_b * n = (k_A * k_B) * n^2 . Letting k_D = (k_A * k_B), we have found that D(n) satisfies the condition for being Ω(n^2).

Comment: Can u plz elaborate a bit?

Comment: @JonSillick: There you go. But really, you should read some basic textbook on algorithms, or programming-and-algorithms, where you'll find some treatment of this subject and probably a few exercises. I'm guessing you're an undergraduate or high-school student - so you could also just ask your teacher or TA to help you wrap your head around all this.

Comment: @JonSillick I think you need to elaborate your question if you want people to elaborate their answers.